# Set Font of Jasper Report in java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I want to set font for Jasper report in Java Code.Is it possible? If yes then please suggest answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using dynamic jasper then you can use :

package

```
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.constants.Font;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.Style;
```

and use those packages like  :-

```
Font columnFont=new Font(10, "SansSerif", false);
Style stringColumnStyle=new Style("stringColumnStyle");
stringColumnStyle.setFont(columnFont);
stringColumnStyle.setBorder(Border.THIN);
stringColumnStyle.setHorizontalAlign(HorizontalAlign.LEFT);
stringColumnStyle.setVerticalAlign(VerticalAlign.MIDDLE);
stringColumnStyle.setBorderColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
```

Comment: i have Data with different font Size,Font Name in Jtable and want to print that value of table same as in Jtable...i know Jtable Model but it sends only object of table....So Any suggestion...

Comment: Hi atul, Can you please elaborate it more..?? i am not able to get what is your problem exactly...??

Comment: If you are using dynamic jasper...And when you are adding columns in jasper report then use package ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.entities.columns.AbstractColumn;

and create object of FastReportBuilder drb = new FastReportBuilder();


AbstractColumn date=ColumnBuilder.getNew().setColumnProperty(arrColumnNameCollection.get(index).toString(),Date.class.getName())
        .setTitle(arrColumnNameDisplayCollection.get(index).toString()).setWidth(sizeForDate).setStyle(dateStyle).setHeaderStyle(headerStyle).build();
        

drb.addColumn(date);